# Preloaded "Core data" database not showing the correct new data after updating the database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, database, core-data

I have a predefined and preloaded database in my project named `Database`, i had define it as follow:
in the `AppDelegate`

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];



NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"]; //este es el que sirve!!! CREE ESTE

//  NSLog(@"store URL %@", storeURL);

// Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"sqlite"];


    if (defaultStorePath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:writableDBPath error:NULL];
    }
}    

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

And in any class i wanna call the data from the database i use:

```
-(NSArray *)sqlCall {


AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MotherWeekly" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[ NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setFetchLimit:1];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
NSString *a =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@==%d",@"id",pageNumber];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:a];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                          error:&error];

[request release];
return objects ;
}
```

**The problem is:** when i update a field in my preloaded database and run it on my simulator or iPhone the data appear to be the old one not the updated one.

**PS:** i had submitted my app to the AppStore before i noticed this problem, so im gonna reject my binary and upload a new version with the working/updated database, so please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your code is not clear: 1) why you define the writableDBPath and then when you create the store URL you use the method "applicationDocumentDirectory". Are you sure you're pointing to a valid URL? 2) before closing the app, did you use the NSManagedObjectContext -save: method to save data in the persistent store?

Comment: The only thing i need is to show the updated data, i think the device cashes the data and show the old records only, forget about my code, and think with me with a way to get the updated data

Comment: So do you mean that you cannot see the updated data even if the same running session? or you cannot see the updated data after closing and then restarting the app?

Comment: if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"sqlite"];
have you checked that your updated db get copied to doc directory.

Comment: I cant see the updated data unless i reset my simulator or delete the app from my device and run my code again!!

Comment: Anyone ?? @viggio24 ??

Comment: you can try this, in your AppDelegate File check if the updated records exist in your table 

NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (count == NSNotFound)
delete your database file from doc directory,
and copy file from resource dir to doc directory

Comment: Please describe more in an answer

Comment: Double check inside your generated sqlite file, to see if updated data is effectively there or not. Also double check with debugger if you are not overwriting the persistent store from the bundle (the preloaded one) to the documents directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the store is not deleted when you have a new updated one. Therefore you see the old values.

If you want to delete the store if there is a new one, you could check for a `NSUserDefault` with a version or something that tells you if an update is necessary. If yes, delete the persistent store, copy the new one and set the user default to the new version.

However, all the user data would be lost then. There are two solutions to this:

1) You can have two persistent stores, one for "static" data and one for user data. However, this might be a bit too complex.

2) Alternatively, you could include information of the changed data and simply update the database (copy only if it does not exist, i.e. if it is a new installation). This would preserve the user data as well. In fact, if the data that needs to be updated is not much, it does not seem to make sense to copy the whole database again.

Indeed, if the database to be copied has less than, say, 10.000 records, copying a core data persistent store might be questionable. You could do a quick background insert at startup instead reading from any kind of file.

Comment: How about adding a new database with the same structure but with a different name, BTW the database dont have a user data

Comment: That's a bad idea because you get more complexity. Just replace it at app startup before assigning the persistent store.